# How to wait for a set of threads to finished or other event in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

Create a thread to the service windows

```
void ServiceManagement::ServiceWorkerThread()
{
    // Periodically check if the service is stopping.

    //Create thread t1
    std::thread t1(Execution);

    while (!m_fStopping ||! "t1 has joined ?")
    {
        // Perform main service function here...
        ::Sleep(1000);  // Simulate some lengthy operations.
    }
    SetEvent(m_hFinishedEvent);

}
```

How to check of thread has finished and joined (t1.join()==TRUE)?

Comment: Make your life easier, and use [`std::future`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future)

Comment: thanks for your guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`std::future`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) for such task. There is member function name [`wait_for`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait_for) with the help of this you can achieve your desired goal.